# Reload tableviewcontroller after user dismisses view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableviewController` and a button where upon click another `UIViewController` will appear

```
    [self presentViewController:newPopupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, when i click the close button in this `UIViewController` (`newPopupViewController`) will be removed and the `UITableVIewController` that was there before will be displayed.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

When the `UITableVIewController` appears i want to reload the table Data. How can i do this.

Comment: retrieve your table when you are dismissing the VC and reload it or reload table in `viewWillAppear ` .

Comment: When presenting a modal to perform a piece of work, you would be best to have the presenter do the dismiss once the required action or update action has been performed. Simplest mechanism is to provide a block property or delegate which is called by your presented controller when an action is performed. In the block/delegate you implement the dismiss when required. `viewWillAppear` is ok for iPhone only apps, but you may find if you go to support iPad with popovers that you need something more reliable as `viewWillAppear` is not called when a popover is dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   // Relead data here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a block. Suppose you have FirstViewController and NewPopupViewController, so in the NewPopupViewController.h file write,

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^ReturnBlock)(BOOL);
```

and in the NewPopupViewController.m file where you dismiss the ViewController set,

```
self.ReturnBlock(YES);
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

So in the FirstViewController where you call the presentViewController write,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NewPopupViewController *newPopupViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"]; // The Identifier should be from the Storyboard
[self presentViewController:newPopupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
[newPopupViewController setReturnBlock:^(BOOL flag)
{
    if (!flag)
    {
       //reload you table here 
    }
}];
```

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this. Can you show me a detailed example on how this is done.

Comment: @Paddy Having gone to the effort to have a block called, it might be better to do the dismiss from inside the block and the table should be reloaded inside completion block of the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` call. If staying as you have shown, I would do the block call in the completion handler.

Comment: One more question, How do i pass a value from `newPopupViewController ` to `FirstViewController ` ?

Comment: The block does not get executed.

Comment: You can pass values like,
 `@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^ReturnBlock)(id, BOOL);`
The Block should work for reference, check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)